# Python error in Mac OS X 10.11.6

Tags: python

I have homebrew installed as well as the system python under 10.11.6. When I try to use pip (or pip3) pip does not run and gives the following error.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix it?

Here are the error messages

```
echo $PYTHON_PATH /Users/paulfons/ase: axion:~ paulfons$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/20160716/shims:/opt/intel//compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.111/mac/bin/intel64:/opt/intel//documentation_2016/en/debugger//gdb-ia/man/:/Users/paulfons/bin:/Users/paulfons/ase/tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/intel//debugger_2016/gdb/intel64/bin
axion:~ paulfons$ pip -V Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 635, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 943, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==8.1.2' distribution was
not found and is required by the application axion:~ paulfons$ pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line
5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 635, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 943, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==8.1.2' distribution was
not found and is required by the application axion:~  paulfons$
```

Comment: You're going to have to format this into something readable.

Comment: Requiring a specific version of pip? What is this thing supposed to do? I don't think I would be using an application that requires a specific version of pip....

Comment: Please try `python -m pip -V` and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to reinstall your pip, or upgrade it using easyinstall. On your MacBook you can run this command on your terminal:

```
sudo easy_install-3.5 --upgrade pip
```